# R: Try to fill in a column with values by certain condition

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, intervals

i really need advice for following task in R:
I have a column with time and one with intervals. For later aggregation I have to set intervals for the time.
Example:
**I have the table:**

```
time   interval

1        NA
2        NA
3        NA
4        NA
5        NA
6        NA
```

**Expecting:**

```
time   interval
1          5
2          5
3          5
4          5
5          5
6         10  
14        15
```

**Code:**

```
count=0
dt = 5
dt_temp = 5

for (i in df_start$time){

if (i<dt) {
df_start$interval[count] =dt

}else{
dt= dt+dt_temp
df_start$interval[count] =dt
}
count = count+1
}
```

**Outcome(or check picture):**

```
time    interval
1           5
2           5
3           5
4           5
4.946      10  (wrong)
5.021      15  (totally wrong)
6.023      20  (totally wrong)
```

I am really going nuts, since I sit nearly half a day to find the problem. 
Thanks in advance!

[Image of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEeoM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, where `ceiling` is used:

```
df$interval <- ceiling(df$time/5)*5
```

such that

```
> df
  time interval
1    1        5
2    2        5
3    3        5
4    4        5
5    5        5
6    6       10
7   14       15
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you :). Best solution, because with the for loop it was too slow. Had 777411 observation

Answer (score 0):

```
df_start$interval = ((df_start$time - 1) %/% 5 + 1) *5
```

Comment: Thank you :). With your solution I noticed that, my datatype is still a character

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df_start <- data.frame(time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,14), interval = 0)

count= 1

dt = 5

dt_temp = 5

for (i in df_start$time){

if (i<=dt) {
df_start$interval[count] =dt

}else{
dt= dt+dt_temp
df_start$interval[count] =dt
}
count = count+1
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I really appreciate your helps! I already found the mistake I made. Since I read a csv.data in, I forgot to check the datatypes. All of them were strings and therefore I couldn´t make any reasonable comparison.